# Force redactor to only display HTML editor view

Tags: redactor, richtext

Is there a way to make a Rich Text field using Redactor, to only display and allow input in the HTML view?

The first step I tried was making a redactor config file that looks like this:

```
{
    "buttons": ["html"],
    "plugins": [],
    "toolbarFixed": false
}
```

But the default view is still the WYSIWYG view. I want the HTML button to be toggled by default...

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it’s possible at all and what’s the benefit of using a WYSIWYG field at all when you don’t use any of the features.

I’d rather use a plain text field or even better, a field type which is optimized for code editing like the Simple Text field type.

https://github.com/craftcms/simple-text/tree/v1

Comment: Great plugin recommendation! The reason for not using a plain text field was to make the code more readable. But this plugin does that!